# Identify connector - fan header

Tags: identification

I am trying to identify the following male connector to find a female counterpart. I do not believe it is a JST connector, and the website I found the matching picture on for my part does not list the connector type. It's typically used on small form factor fans.

[image]

Comment: Without measuring it and giving us the pin pitch and showing a close-up of the female housing, you'll only get guesses. Why don't you think it's a JST? Have you looked at Molex?

Comment: Why not lookup the spec sheet for the fan (or whatever it was used to plug into)? It might include a the part # or name for its connector.

Comment: Fan didn't have any identifying markings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd bet my shirt<sup>1</sup> it *is* a JST. But JST is a brand, and they have lots of different connectors. This one looks like JST XH range.

[Digikey link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/XHP-2/455-2266-ND/555485)

[Pololu link](https://www.pololu.com/product/1164)

It really looks like it, I'd say:

[image]

<sup>1: Not sure you want my shirt anyway</sup>

Comment: i searched through my local distributors jst connectors and couldn't find one that looked like this thats why I assumed it wasn't. indeed thats the one!

Comment: Cool, I keep my shirt, then.

Comment: I probably didn't want it anyways.. :)